# projects come or coming from different countries

Tags: word-usage, present-continuous, verb-usage

I am wondering which of the following sentences makes the most sense:

1. 250+ projects coming from 100 different countries
2. 250+ projects come from 100 different countries
3. 250+ projects from 100 different countries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of them makes the "most sense". They all mean different things:

1.) is continuous. So you're talking about something very current.

2.) this one needs more context. But it is more demonstrative. Has a feeling of someone pointing at this fact and saying: "So if you look at this here, you'll see that approximately 250+ projects come from 100 different countries."

3.) The third is like a statement of what someone has. E.g: "I've dealt with 250+ projects from 100 different countries."

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add comments yet, but can you please modify your question to complete those sentences? Only the second sentence seems to have all parts of a sentence, but that still does not sound quite right. All you really have here is a noun (qualified by adjectives) or subject.

Also, you should use "makes" instead of "make", since the subject of your question - "which (one)" - is singular.